# Pass MDC parameter to file name in Log4cxx

Tags: log4j, logging, log4cxx

I can able to get a parameter[ PID] at my program , then put this parameter to context using MDC

```
  MDC::put( "pid", strProcessId);
```

And i can log process id by adding this to config

```
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{pid} "/>
  </layout>
```

But i want to pass this parameter to the file name at config such as

```
 <param name="file" value="LogFile%X{pid}.log" />
```

**But this does not work...Anyway to do this in log4cxx?**

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in Logback logging framework: http://logback.qos.ch/